# Acces denied 'root'@'@localhost'

Tags: mysql, wamp

i'm having an issue with wamp when testing my php connexion to the bdd,

everything is working: wamp is green, my site is online but when try to request my bdd with

```
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basepourplan;charset=utf8', 'root', 'proot');
```

i got

```
 Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)
```

(acces denied for the user:)

Ive followed a tuto which made me do this:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD(' monmotdepasse '); 
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ' 
monmotdepasse ' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

this in config.ini.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']= 'localhost'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']= 'monmotdepasse';
```

and finaly this in my php.ini

```
; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode). 
mysqli.default_host ='localhost' 
; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode). 
mysqli.default_user ='root' 
; file will be able to reveal the password as well. 
mysqli.default_pw ='monmotdepasse'
```

and yet i cant connect it succesfully; the problem seems to comme from the root@@localhost with the 2@.

Can someone help ? TY

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL password setting has spaces around the password, but you didn't enter these space in your connection :-(

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD(' monmotdepasse ');
```

but

```
mysqli.default_pw ='monmotdepasse'
```

don't have the surrounding spaces at all.

Comment: However, I think there maybe other problems, since the original question's code is not showing enough.

Comment: yes its because it is not my password i've write it to not communicate it